# What is the best way to export an object literal with ES6/2015?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Seemingly a very simple task...

```
export default function() {
    return {
        googleClientID:'xxxx'
    }
}
```

Is it the best way to export object literal with app settings?

Comment: The syntax is `export default <expression>` or `export var name = <expression>;`.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can export object itself:

```
export default {
    googleClientID:'xxxx'
};
```

The difference is that in your case you will get brand new object every time you call exported function. In this case you will get the same object every time. Depends on what you need.

Comment: Thank you, madox2. Your syntaxis is simpler and solve the task of passing a global settings.

Comment: When importing, why does `import { googleClientID } from 'file'` not work?

Comment: @aashah7 I am using default export, therefore you need to import it by default: `import googleClientID from 'file'`. You are importing it by name so you need to use named export: `export const googleClientID = 'xxx'`. Notice that destructuring is not intended to work with imports.

Comment: Missing an explanation on how to import it... Sugget to add it...

Comment: ESLint is complaining if I do this (no-anonymous-default-export).

Answer (score 13):

You can simply export an **object**

```
export default { googleClientID:'xxxx' };
```

A [**default export**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Description) can be a function, a class, an object or anything else. This value is to be considered as the "main" exported value since it will be the simplest to import.

Comment: The second example should probably be `export var foo = ...`.

Comment: @FelixKling nope nothing like that.

Comment: Thank you guys. I try to force myself to let. so export default let foo = {

Comment: but simplicity is the queen, so export default {} is the way. 
Sorry for a silly questions :-)

Comment: I assumed you wanted to create a named export, but maybe you don't? `export default foo = ...` will throw an error if you didn't declare `foo` anywhere before and I don't see the point of assigning the value to a variable if you just want to export it. Just to be clear: `export default foo = 42;` is basically the same as doing `module.exports = (foo = 42);` in CommonJS (which isn't very common I believe).

Comment: @void Your second example isn't right, the assignment is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

@madox2 's and @void 's answer may be some kind of common misunderstanding.

I just ran into a similar problem while issuing a PR to [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) -- [#18725](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/18725/#issuecomment-332170138). The typescript compiler complains about the generated files.

A example should be:

```ts
// ...
import zip from "./zip";
import zipObject from "./zipObject";
import zipObjectDeep from "./zipObjectDeep";
import zipWith from "./zipWith";

export default {
  // ...
  zip,
  zipObject,
  zipObjectDeep,
  zipWith
};
```

At the first glance, i didn't think its my problem. Because i just copy the code from `lodash-es`. But then i can't find any simple approach to remove the errors.

So I go to the **[spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports)** for answer. Wow, the spec doesn't talk about **default export of an object**, if I read it right.

#### Conclusion:

The follow is spec-respected:

```js
export { googleClientID:'xxxx' }
```

---

Just found some more references:

- https://medium.com/@timoxley/named-exports-as-the-default-export-api-670b1b554f65#a279
- https://medium.com/@rauschma/note-that-default-exporting-objects-is-usually-an-anti-pattern-if-you-want-to-export-the-cf674423ac38

Answer (score 1):

Exporting: not nicest, but handy when importing later.

```js
export const ROOT = '/tmp/test'
export const EXT = '.backup'
// ... and so on
```

Importing: cleanest usage (and we usually import more than export).

```js
import { ROOT, EXT } from './literals.js'
const file = ROOT + yourFileName + EXT
```