# How to export multiple functions ES6

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex

I'm working in a vue project, I'm very new to vue.

We have a db_handler.js in out /src/utility folder. 
It looks like this:

```
import fakeApiCall from "./mock";
import axios from "axios";
import { DEBUG_MODE, API_ENDPOINT } from "./namespaces";

function fetchData(method, slug, payload) {
  //axios.defaults.headers.withCredentials = true;
  //return (!DEBUG_MODE) ? axios[method](`${API_ENDPOINT}${slug}`, payload) : fakeApiCall(slug);
  return axios[method](`${API_ENDPOINT}${slug}`, payload);

  /*var url = "http://localhost:8080" + slug

  return axios({
    method: method,
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': payload
    }
  });*/
}

function sendData(method, slug, payload) {
  axios[method](`${API_ENDPOINT}${slug}`, payload);
}

export default fetchData
```

What I need to know:
How can I export my `sendData()`?
They used a short syntax so far because they only exported one function. 
How can I export multiple functions? I also want the names to remain "fetchData" and "sendData"

EDIT: 
I tried to apply the approaches of Iamhuynq and Bergi, but now something goes south. I am importing the functions first and foremost in 
`moduleUser.js` and `authUser.js` which reside in `/src/store/modules`.
The `authUser.js` is used for the identification of the user, so of course it is used in the login screen. When I now try to login, I get "Type Error: Object undefined". I guess this is because the functions returning the server response are somehow failing or not found.

The codebase connected to this behavior is the Login screen, the db_handler which Ive already shown you and a module called "moduleAuth.js".

First, the login screen looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <p>Name:</p>
    <div class="inputbox">
      <input ref="username" type='text' v-on:keydown.enter="userLogin">
    </div>
    <p>Password:</p>
    <div class="inputbox">
      <input class="inputbox" ref="password" type='password' v-on:keydown.enter="userLogin">
    </div>
    <p>{{error}}</p>
    <button v-on:click='userLogin'>Login</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import store from "../store/store";

import { AUTH_REQUEST } from "../store/actions/auth";

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      error: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    userLogin: function(){
      this.error = '';
      store.dispatch(AUTH_REQUEST,{username: this.$refs.username.value, password: this.$refs.password.value})
      .then((res) => {
        this.$router.push({path: '/profile'});
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.error = err;
      });
      this.$refs.password.value = '';
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.inputbox{
  width: 25%;
}
</style>
```

`moduleAuth.js`, from which the `AUTH_REQUEST` vue-action is coming, looks like this:

```
import axios from "axios";
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import {fetchData, sendData} from "../../utility/db_handler";

import { USER_REQUEST } from "../actions/user";
import { AUTH_REQUEST, AUTH_LOGOUT, AUTH_FAIL, AUTH_SUCCESS } from "../actions/auth";
import { METHOD_POST, JWT } from "../../utility/namespaces";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const storeAuth = {
  state: {
    token: localStorage.getItem(JWT) || '',
    loginState: ''
  },
  getters: {
    isAuthenticated: state => !!state.token,
    getLoginState: state => state.loginState
  },
  mutations: {
    [AUTH_REQUEST]: (state) => {
      state.loginState = 'pending';
    },
    [AUTH_FAIL]: (state) => {
      state.loginState = 'error';
    },
    [AUTH_SUCCESS]: (state, mToken) => {
      state.loginState = '';
      state.token = mToken;
    },
    [AUTH_LOGOUT]: (state) => {
      return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>{
        state.loginState = '';
        state.token = '';
        localStorage.removeItem(JWT);
        resolve();
        //Catch?
      })
    }
  },
  actions: {
    [AUTH_REQUEST]: ({ commit, dispatch }, uObj) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit(AUTH_REQUEST);
        fetchData(METHOD_POST, '/login',{
            username: uObj.username,
            password: uObj.password
          }).then(function (res) {
          commit(AUTH_SUCCESS,res.headers.authorization);
          localStorage.setItem(JWT,res.headers.authorization);
          axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = res.headers.authorization;
          dispatch(USER_REQUEST);
          resolve(res.data);
        }).catch(function(err) {
          commit(AUTH_FAIL);
          reject(err);
        })
      })
    },
    [AUTH_LOGOUT]: ({ commit}) => {
      commit(AUTH_LOGOUT);
    }
  }
}

export default storeAuth
```

Now, if just roll back the changes to the export/import sections, everything works. So the problem should definitely be connected to this.

Comment: Don't use a default export, use named exports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `export`

```
export function sendData() {...}
```

and you can import like this

```
import fetchData, { sendData } from '/src/utility/db_handler.js;'
```

Comment: what goes between the {}? Is there any way to export them with export default {} pattern, while keeping the names as I described in OP?

Comment: You should also make `fetchData` a named export

Comment: @baryon123 Don't use that "*`export default {}` pattern*".

Comment: @Bergi Why? Its used practically everywhere in the project

Comment: @baryon123 Because named exports are much superior. Exporting objects is mostly used for compatibility with commonjs.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, could you then please show me an example of your approach?

Comment: Just use `export function fetchData(…) { … }` alongside the `export function sendData(…) { … }` as in this answer, and drop the default export. Then `import { fetchData, sendData } from …`.

Comment: To both @Bergi and iamhuynq: Somehow the import/export seems to fail. See my Edit in OP.

Comment: Does the syntax to call the named, imported functions somehow change?

Answer (score 2):

Here my suggestion is, if you are exporting more then one function, you should use export method instead of export default. It will make your code more readable and ll use for future debugging.

```
export function function1(params) {
 .......
}

export function function2() {
 ......
}
```

Here there is a two way to import functions

1. by using `import { function1, function2} from "./exportedFunctionFile"` make sure you are using same function name as you exported!
2. other method is use *** as yourVariableName** example `import * as myFunctions from "./exportedFunctionFile"` this would use when you are exporting too many functions now you can use your imported functions as `myfunctions.function1()`

if you want to export using default key word, export functions as object example `export default {function1,function2}` and you could use it like `import * as myFunctions from "./exportedFunctionFile"` which is similar as a second way of importion.

Hope it will Help you

Answer (score 1):

export the functions in an object

```
export default {
    sendData: sendData,
    fetchData: fetchData
}
```

then to use

```
import * as DBHandler from '@/src/utility/db_handler'
...
DBHandler.sendData()
```

Comment: Never default-export object literals. Use named exports instead (and `import * as DBHandler from …` if you want a namespace).

Comment: @Bergi can you explain why not to default-export object literals, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34619661/3462319) has basically the same thing

Comment: That answer is to a question asking specifically for that. It doesn't discuss whether it's a bad practice or whether there are better alternatives at all.

Comment: not working unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

On the function files

```
func1(params) {
...
}

func2(params) {
...
}

export default default {
    function1: function1,
    function2: function2
}
```

---

On the other file

```
import * as _ from './module address'
```

then

```
_.default.func1.call(args)
_.default.func2.call(args)
```